# Programmatically Insert Text from External File

Tags: lyx

I am looking to insert text from an external file to LyX. The external file (simple ascii file) has a single line but it will change on future document interations based on modelling output. Is there a way to programmatically reference the file so that it updates as the ascii file updates? Similar to inserting an image (which updates automatically).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can input any text-based file by the `\input{}` command. So the following example will

```latex
\input{test.txt}
```

Make sure you are in TeX mode, by selecting `insert TeX code` from the menu. You should see a red box.

[image: Red box]

Comment: could you add a more detailed answer?

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you... I guess one note though is that when I reference two different files in two different locations in the document, they seem to be getting grouped together. Is this normal?